# proper way of adding properties to prototypes in my code

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

Hey Im trying to add 'event' and a callback function "fun" to a prototype of MyEvents and don't understand one part of the code below!

```
function MyEvents(events){
this.events={};
}

MyEvents.prototype.adding=function(event,func){
var array=[]
this.array.push(func);
this.array.push(event);
this.events[event] = array; //I don't understand this part-why is that necessary?
}
```

Could someone please explain?
Thank you!!

Comment: I feel like there should be only `array` instead of `this.array`. Do you have some more context?

Comment: I tried it without this. and it didn't work as well unless I included this.events[event] = array; and I just dint get why I have to include that..Its just part of an exercise and for now I just have to add a callback func and an event to an array to the prototype

Comment: @javascripting: Show us the rest of the code. Where else is the array used? Then you'll know why you want (need) to store it in that `.events` object.

Comment: the only additional info I have is the following: newEvent = new MyEvent(); newEvent.adding('greet', function(name){
      return "Hey, " + name + "!";
    }) // Array.isArray(newEvent.events.greet) should be true and //     var handling = newEvent.events.greet[0]; --> 

 handling('mike') should result in 'Hello, mike!';

Comment: Well, yes, how would you get `newEvents.events.greet` to be an array without storing `array` in there? That's why it's necessary - without the statement, your code does not do what is expected.

Comment: Oh wait I actually understand it now I think-i do push the callback and the event into the array, but then I need to 'declare' the array where I pushed everything insight it, as a value of the property events of the object-right? but then why do I only say this.events[event] = array; and not also this.events[func] = array; ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to do something like this:

```
//constructor function
function MyEvents(){
    this.events={};
}
//extending the prototype with a function called adding  
MyEvents.prototype.adding = function(event,func){
    this.events[event] = func
}
//instantiating a new object using the new operator on the constructor function
my_new_obj = new MyEvents()
//calling the adding function on the prototype and passing it the two arguments
my_new_obj.adding('test',function greet(){console.log('Hello')})
//calling the function you just added
my_new_obj['events']['test']()
```

Also, note that this can be very powerful because the methods (functions) you add to the prototype can access your instantiated my_new_obj properties.

Comment: No, OP really wants an array of functions.